# Is there a way to omit the definitions (line markers) at the top of the C-preprocessor output?

Tags: c, gcc, llvm, preprocessor

If I process the following `test.def` input file with `gcc -C -x c -E  test.def`:

```
#define TEST foo 
int TEST;
```

I would like the output to be just:

```
int foo;
```

Instead I get:

```
# 1 "test.def"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "test.def"

int foo;
```

Is there a way I can omit those extra lines at the top?

Comment: That sounds like a job for `tail -5`.

Comment: Try `gcc -C -x c -E test.def | tail -n +4` but why?

Comment: @n.m. I am working on X-macros (see my recent questions/answers), and I would like to automatically generate preprocessed files to ease my IDE (Eclipse) and my colleagues :) understanding the data structures.

Comment: I sometimes use c preprocessor to do scripting jobs - generate stubs and such in non C codes (sometimes not even codes). Something similar here?

Comment: @unwind Will it always be 5 lines long?

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya Yep

Comment: @Antonio it is not just about the first few lines then. These things can appear in the middle of the output too. I would suggest removing the lines that start with a #. sed or grep with negation flag maybe.

Comment: Try `gcc -E -P` then. You may or may not make it any easier for anyone though. Whatever works for you...

Comment: `cpp test.def | grep -v "^# "`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

These are not just on the top - but instead they're the line markers that the C preprocessors use to convey the source code positions where certain lines come from, to the C compiler.

---

With GCC this is easy, as [GCC supports the `-P` switch](https://linux.die.net/man/1/gcc), and [so does llvm Clang](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangCommandLineReference.html#preprocessor-flags):

> `-P`. Inhibit generation of linemarkers in the output from the
>   preprocessor. This might be useful when running the preprocessor on something that is not C code, and will be sent to a program which might be confused by the linemarkers.

Thus, use `gcc -E -P -x c`.

Also, I'd not use `-C` (retain comments), as it seems that with it `gcc` adds some comments from implicit header files.

Comment: Great! One drawback is that apparently it also removes new lines (at least, that changed when I added -P)

Comment: @Antonio ah, so it seems, but it would hardly matter, now would it? It is still valid source.

Comment: It matters a bit because I am using this trick to create "human readable" code. But I had anyway to add a `__CR__` to be replaced later on (by `sed` or something similar) with a new line and some spaces for better formatting (e.g. when definining the struct), so adding a `__SPACER__` won't be a problem